# InitialMigration empty even though there are data objects in Azure Service

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, entity-framework-migrations

I have been having trouble working with migrations and an Azure Sql Database for the past couple of weeks.

I run enable-migrations and a migrations folder with a congfiguration file is created. 
I then run Add-Migration InitialCreate and a migration is created with empty Up() and Down() methods.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project MyService.
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
Scaffolding migration 'InitialCreate'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your 
current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to 
your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional 
changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you 
can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration InitialCreate' again.
```

I deleted an old database from my App Service and created a new one. This is now being targeted in my Web.config:

```
<add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyService-20180212689875.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyService-20180212578997;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have a feeling my code is targeting the old database which has been deleted on azure but holds the tables for the objects I'm now trying to add.

**Update:**
Removed the data objects and created a migration and it has been populated with the Delete code for non-existent tables(which existed in my last database). Definitely an issue with pointing to the right place. Any ideas?

Pretty new to Azure so not sure where to look to try and fix this.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Removed the data objects and created a migration and it has been populated with the Delete code for non-existent tables(which existed in my last database). Definitely an issue with pointing to the right place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After adding migration, remember to enter "**update-database**" in Package Manager Console, which command runs the Up method to create the database and then it runs the Seed method to **populate the database**.

> I have a feeling my code is targeting the old database which has been deleted on azure but holds the tables for the objects I'm now trying to add.

According to the code you provided, you set the database in Local in web.config and delete the database on Azure, but you could populate data to the deleted database on azure. There is no possible to achieve it.

Actually, when you publish you Web App to Azure, you could pick on the "**Excute Code First Migrations**" in Visual Studio and check if the **TestContext** is the database connection that you use now.

[image]

Each time you get both of them and after migrations, you will populate the data to the latest the database on Azure. You could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to know the details about Code First Migrations and Deployment.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been running Update-Database. I actually ended up deleting out my data objects and running an Add-Migration and it created an Up() consisting of removing the tables...which didn't exist in my database. I think something has become very confused somewhere. Azure says it's  pointing at the right DB but it won't allow me to run the sample code which was downloaded from Azure to populate the ToDoItem table. I think it's a lost cause. Going to build a website instead of an App because there are too many issues with App Services and Xamarin that aren't documented properly

Comment: You could try to delete your configuration and enable migration again.

Comment: Tried that multiple times